# Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) in Python (Multichannel error)

Tags: python, deep-learning, scikit-image, ssim

I want to calculate the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between a generated and a target image (that have been picked randomly from an array of images).

This is what I have tried-

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim

print(tar_image.shape)
print(gen_image.shape)

ssim_skimg = ssim(tar_image, gen_image,
                  data_range = gen_image.max() - gen_image.min(), 
                  multichannel = True)

print("SSIM: based on scikit-image = ", ssim_skimg)
```

But I am getting this output:

```
(1, 128, 128, 3)
(1, 128, 128, 3)

ValueError: win_size exceeds image extent.  If the input is a multichannel (color) image, set multichannel=True.
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong and how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 channel images, so you should use the `channel_axis` argument.

Also you should remove the first dimension of your images to get `(128,128,3)` shapes

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim 

tar_image = np.zeros((128, 128, 3))
gen_image = np.zeros((128, 128, 3))

ssim_skimg = ssim(tar_image, gen_image, channel_axis=-1, data_range=255)
```

Comment: Your example leads to: ValueError: win_size exceeds image extent. Either ensure that your images are at least 7x7; or pass win_size explicitly in the function call, with an odd value less than or equal to the smaller side of your images. If your images are multichannel (with color channels), set channel_axis to the axis number corresponding to the channels.

Comment: Indeed, the original answer was written with scikit-image < 0.19, I edited it to fit to current latest version 0.21 ;)

Comment: What if images are normalized between 0 and 1? I guess data_range=1

Comment: yes, you should specify what data range you are using. if you do not specify a datarange, you will get a warning telling you to do so